# Java expression to take all numbers after a set of symbols

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking at some regular expressions in Java but I can't get what I want to do. My program is a calculator and I need to get the **second operator**. To do this, two requirements need to be met:

- The first operator may contain a "-" symbol (could be negative).
- After that, I just want to save all the numbers (there are not decimals) behind the +, -, * and / symbols.
- It is necessary to ignore the equal symbol at the end.

For this implementation there are only two operators. For example, my inputs could be:

```
-23+253=
34-83767=
-74567*3229765=
```

I´m taking the first operator using this regex:

```
this.display.getText().split("(?<=\\d)[-+*/]");
```

Comment: Have you seen [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) ? It's a website for making regexs and full explanation of every piece. It's made by Grant Skinner, the G in gskinner and also the Skinner.

Comment: A few problems here: [1] The regex you pass to `split` describes _the separator_, and split gives you everything between the separators, _discarding the separators_. You either need to have your regex be the numbers (so that those are discarded and the operators are returned), or use `Matcher` and `Pattern`, or try to describe in your regexp the concept of the space between numbers and digits (it'd be entirely a lookahead/lookbehind). Secondly, your first paragraph talks about the second operator, but your examples do not have 2 operators in them. Hence, your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This will split on all the operators and signs and store them in an array, in order, for further processing.  It works by surrounding each operator with a special string and then splitting on that string.  It then streams the result to catch any blank string prior to returning the array.

```
String [] expressions = { "-23+253=",
                          "4-83767=",
                          "74567*3229765=",
                          "(38+5)*7.6"};

String operands = "([-+/*=()])"; 
 
for (String exp : expressions) {
     String[] tokens = Arrays.stream(exp.replaceAll(operands, "#$1#").split("#"))
             .filter(str->!str.isBlank()).toArray(String[]::new);
     
     System.out.printf("%-15s --> %s%n",exp,Arrays.toString(tokens));
}
```

prints

```
-23+253=        --> [-, 23, +, 253, =]
4-83767=        --> [4, -, 83767, =]
74567*3229765=  --> [74567, *, 3229765, =]
(38+5)*7.6      --> [(, 38, +, 5, ), *, 7.6]
```

Answer (score 3):

What *may* be more beneficial would be a Mathematical Expression Parser where all the components of a mathematical expression can be placed into a String[] array, for example:

```
/**
 * This method will parse a math expression (equation) string, even with various bracket
 * types or nested brackets and Unicode math operators or numerical
 * characters like PI ()) into a String[] Array.
 * <p>
 * Signed and unsigned integer or floating point values can be within the
 * supplied mathematical expression.
 * <p>
 * Whitespaces are ignored during parsing and will not be contained within
 * the returned String[] Array as an array element.<br>
 *
 * @param expression (String) The mathematical expression to parse into a String[] Array.<br>
 *
 * @return (String[] Array)
 */
public String[] parseMathExpression(String expression) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String number = "";
    String[] chr = expression.codePoints()
            .mapToObj(cp -> new String(Character.toChars(cp)))
            .toArray(size -> new String[size]);

    for (String c : chr) {
        if (c.matches("\\s")) {
            if (!number.isEmpty()) {
                list.add(number);
                number = "";
            }
        }
        else if (c.matches("[0-9]") || c.matches("[\\.]") || (c.matches("[-]") && number.isEmpty())) {
            number += c;
        }
        else if (!c.matches("\\d") && !number.isEmpty()) {
            list.add(number);
            number = "";
            list.add(c);
        }
        else {
            list.add(c);
        }
    }
    if (!number.isEmpty()) {
        list.add(number);
    }
    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseMathExpression("-23+253=")));
// Will Output:  [-23, +, 253, =]

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseMathExpression("34-83767=")));
// Will Output:  [34, -, 83767, =]

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseMathExpression("-74567*3229765=")));
// Will Output:  [-74567, *, 3229765, =]

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parseMathExpression("(2+-8)+(8.5-0.5)=")));
// Will Output:  [(, 2, +, -8, ), +, (, 8.5, -, 0.5, ), =]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Regex:

Here is a pragmatic regex that allow you to choose exactly what you want using named groups :

```
"^(?<sign>-?)(?<firstNumber>\\d+)(?<operator>[-+*/])(?<numberBehindOp>\\d+)(?<equal>=)"
```

### Explanation :

1. `(?<sign>-?)` a named group capturing the minus `-`if exist `?`. It is callable later as `sign`.
2. `^` Start of the line or of the string.
3. `(?<firstNumber>\\d+)` a named group capturing one or more digits `\d+` (escaped for Java string with an extra ''). It is callable later as **firstNumber**.
4. `(?<operator>[-+*/])` a named group capturing the operators `[-+*/]`callable later as **operator**.
5. ...

### Demo :

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TestRegex1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Inputs to test
        String[] InputLines = {
            "-23+253=",
            "34-83767=",
            "-74567*3229765="
        };

        // Regex
        String pattern = "^(?<sign>-?)(?<firstNumber>\\d+)(?<operator>[-+*/])(?<numberBehindOp>\\d+)(?<equal>=)";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Test all the inputs
        for (String input : InputLines) {

            // Apply the regex
            Matcher m = r.matcher(input);

            // Display the input string with its captured group named 'numberBehindOp'
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println("Input: " + input);
                System.out.println("numberBehindOp: " + m.group("numberBehindOp"));
                // System.out.println("firstNumber: " + m.group("firstNumber"));
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.println("No match found for input: " + input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Uncomment this line :

```
// System.out.println("firstNumber: " + m.group("firstNumber"));
```

to see the another named group ;)

### Tip:

To achieve the final regex, I just iterate from a working regex matching all the line :

```
"^-?\d+[-+*/]\d+="
```

then added the named groups.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```java
s.replaceAll("(.+?)([-+*/])(-?.+)=", "$1 $2 $3").split(" ")
```

```
[-23, +, 253]
[34, -, 83767]
[-74567, *, 3229765]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regular expression I made:

```
[+\-/*](-?\d+)=$
```

`[+\-/*]` - Matches +, -, /, and -. The - needs to be escaped or regex will parse it differently.

`(-?\d+)` - One or more digits, possibly preceded by a -

`=` - Matches an equal sign at the end

`$` - The end of the text

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something. Theres a "=" symbol at the end. For instance, the input could be: -23+253= or -74567*3229765=. Is it easy to ignore the equal symbol and keep the logic?

Comment: @Joncarre Updated my answer